# Change layout opacity except for Progressbar

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout, android-progressbar

I have an app that uses a circular progress bar.

I had like to change the opacity of the whole layout until it finished loading.

Something like this:

[image]

I manage to change the opacity of the layout by using:

```
cl = findViewById( R.id.Discover_Layout );
cl.setAlpha( 0.45f );
```

However, it changes the opacity of the `ProgressBar` as well.

I tried to use:

```
cl = findViewById( R.id.Discover_Layout );
cl.setAlpha( 0.45f );

pb_Discover = findViewById( R.id.pb_Discover );
pb_Discover.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
pb_Discover.setAlpha( 1f );
```

But it still kept the ProgressBar with Opacity.

How can I exclude the `ProgressBar` from the layout Opacity?

Thank you

Comment: can you post xml of whole root layout of progressbar

Comment: if your **pb_Discover** are a child in  **Discover_Layout** try to extract it to different layout like `framelayout` which has **pb_Discover** and **Discover_Layout**

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the `Discover_Layout` is the parent layout which contains the `pb_Discover`  progress bar. so changing the parent opacity will reflect in child views too.you can create a `framelayout` as parent layout and add `Discover_Layout` and pb_Discover  as 2 separate child views. so the change in opacity of `Discover_Layout` does not affect the `pb_Discover`  progressbar.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/frame_layout_badge"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

< ----Discover_Layout---/>

< ----pb_Discover---/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Bytheway its better to name view ids to start with a small letter

Answer (score 0):

I think your discover layout is parent of progress view.
You have to make background view with opacity.